# indexPath.row updating incorrectly when static or scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a table, the table works with no problems for scrolling.  The issue starts when I click on a row and want to retrieve the row number using indexPath.row.

I looked through all the posts I could find on this site for a solution, but nothing offered previously helps with my scenario unfortunately.

My cellForRowAtIndexPath stores the row value in 'selectedRow'.  In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I display the value using NSLog and here is what happens.

When I run the app, the first 2 rows display on screen.  If I press either row before I do anything else, both rows return 1.

If I scroll down so that the third and fourth rows are displayed, both rows return 3.

So it is displaying the value of whichever row is displayed last on-screen as the value for both.

If I then scroll back up the list, pressing rows returns 0.

Everything I have read points to something in the cellForRowAtIndexPath causing the problem, but I am at a loss as to what it is.  I have read multiple posts here and also tried reading indexPath.row in different parts of the code.

Any help offered is appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;

PosterURLstartpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@","https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185",[[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] aPosterpath]];
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL : [NSURL URLWithString:PosterURLstartpath] placeholderImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder1.png"]];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;    
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
cell.textLabel.text = [[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] aTitle];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.textLabel.text,@"\n"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *StringReleaseYear = [[[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] aReleaseYear] substringToIndex: 4];

if (![StringReleaseYear isEqualToString:@"0000"]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.textLabel.text,StringReleaseYear];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.textLabel.text,@"\n"];
}

if ([[[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] aType]   isEqual: @"tv"]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.textLabel.text,@"(TV series)"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.textLabel.text,@"\n"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.textLabel.text,[[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] aCharacter]];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.textLabel.text,@"\n"];
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath Row %ld",(long)selectedRow);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectedRow value is printed expectedly. Because you are increasing the value of selectedRow in every call for cell filler method.
If you want to know which tableviewcell is pressed you should use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` with `indexPath` value

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath Row %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    }
```

above code should print the true row number for you.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks meth, you rock.